# Trying to display game information after selecting a team from the drop down

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have data values for teams and the games that are played in a XML file that has the following structure

```
<Schedule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Teams>
          <Team>Sandlot</Team>
          <Team>Rangers</Team>
          <Team>little guys</Team>
   </Teams>
   <Game status="Played">
          <Home_Team>Sandlot</Home_Team>
          <Away_Team>Rangers</Away_Team>
          <Date>2014-01-10</Date>
          <Home_Team_Score>7</Home_Team_Score>
          <Away_Team_Score>9</Away_Team_Score>
      </Game>
  </schedule>
```

I am trying to create a drop down list of all the teams and then when a team is selected, display all of their games and the details about them.

I am using javascript to load the stylesheet which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/Schedule">
    <table class="listing">
        <tr><th>Team</th>
            <td><select name="Team" class="listing" id="teamlist">
                <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="team" /> -->
                <xsl:for-each select="Teams">
                    <option>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Team" />
                    </option>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="button" value="Submit Team" onclick="displayGames()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the javascript I am using to try and display it on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    var teamL="teamlist.xsl";

    function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
        xhttp.send();
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc(xmlFile);
    var xsltTeamDoc=loadXMLDoc(teamListFile);


    function createXDoc(xFile, PID)
    {
            xDoc=loadXMLDoc(xFile);
            return xDoc;
    }  

    function runTransform(xDoc, xsltDoc) {

            var xProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();  
            xProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
            var resultDoc = xProcessor.transformToDocument(xDoc);   
            var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
            var resultStr = serializer.serializeToString(resultDoc);
            return resultStr;
    }
    function init()
    {
        var teamListElem=document.getElementById("teamlist");
        teamListElem.innerHTML=runTransform(xmlDoc,xsltTeamDoc);
    }
</script>
```

when the page loads, the init function runs and displays the id "teamlist"

```
 <body onload="init()">

  <form name="sForm">
<div id="teamlist"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

I still need to work on creating a function to do the calculations to display info too.

my current problem is I can't get the drop down to contain more than the first team in the "Team" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that your schedule XML document is malformed. The opening tag is capitalized `<Schedule>` and the closing tag is lowercase `</schedule>`. That is causing an XML serializer error. Try capitalizing your closing tag `</Schedule>`. Also, you haven't posted the HTML here so I'm assuming the HTML file you created includes some div or other html element with an id of "teamlist". If that is the case, you should be able to see the dropdown after fixing your XML markup assuming you have all 3 files (xml, xslt, html) in the same directory on your web server. Some browsers may throw up a cross-domain warning if you try to load them up locally.

Next, you need to restructure your XML scheme. The `<Team>` nodes should all belong to the same parent `<Teams>` node. Yours all belong to different parent nodes. Restructure like this:

```
    <Schedule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Teams>
        <Team>Sandlot</Team>
        <Team>Rangers</Team>
        <Team>little guys</Team>
    </Teams>
   <Game status="Played">
      <Home_Team>Sandlot</Home_Team>
      <Away_Team>Rangers</Away_Team>
      <Date>2014-01-10</Date>
      <Home_Team_Score>7</Home_Team_Score>
      <Away_Team_Score>9</Away_Team_Score>
  </Game>
</Schedule>
```

Then, you need to change your XSLT templates. Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table class="listing">
            <tr><th>Team</th>
                <td><select name="teamlist" class="listing" id="teamlist">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="button" value="Submit Team" onclick="display()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Team">
        <option>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </option>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Game">

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now you can see that the first template matches the root level "/", and applies templates to it. This will loop over your team nodes and create options for each one using the second template. The third template matches Game nodes and contains no output - this will suppress the extra game information from being rendered after the option tags in your select tag.

Comment: I do have the closing tag capitalized, I just mistyped when I typed it in here   Here is my body in the html    <body onload="init()">

<form name="sForm">
 <div id="teamlist"></div>
</form>
</body>   which I have added above, it is now showing the dropdown but it is empty

Comment: I have the info being displayed but not in the dropdown box.  it is showing below and the dropdown box is still empty.  This is based on my changes to the teamlist.xsl stylesheet and the references to the elements in the XML data file

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, I was able to get the dropdown to display with my changes above but trying to incorporate your changes, it disappeared on me again.  How are you applying the template /Schedule/Teams?  is this a standard in XSLT?  That template is not defined.  Is it just looking at the elements under that?

Comment: Try select="/Teams/Team" in your for-each, and then select="." in your xsl:value-of. That should get the teams to reappear. Regarding the /Schedule/Teams question - that match attribute can be safely removed.

Comment: Awesome, yes that did it now on to populate the game info somehow :)